# basic information about holder in android

Tags: android

I'm searching for some information about "holder" in android...because I've seen some code that used it in using checkbox in gridview...but I couldn't find basic information about it. I'll be happy if anyone can help me.
here is a part of a code that used holder :

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(
                        R.layout.galleryitem, null);
                holder.imageview = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbImage);
                holder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemCheckBox);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }
            else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            holder.checkbox.setId(position);
            holder.imageview.setId(position);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code might call `findViewById()` frequently during the scrolling of `ListView`, which can slow down performance. Even when the Adapter returns an inflated view for recycling, you still need to look up the elements and update them. A way around repeated use of `findViewById()` is to use the "view holder" design pattern.

A `ViewHolder` object stores each of the component views inside the tag field of the Layout, so you can immediately access them without the need to look them up repeatedly.

For more info [refer here](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder)

Answer (score 0):

ViewHolder is used to improve the performance of list scroll here.

Here's a piece of information that might interest you extracted from [Android Developer Website](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder).

Answer (score 0):

Using ViewHolder allow you to avoid of calling findViewById() in every getView() method

Answer (score 0):

In android, listview use convert view to get better performance, it will reuse the list item view with avoiding create view every time, and the view holder is used to keep subview reference in the convert view. You can dig into the listview source code for details, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`ViewHolder` is used to avoid an expensive call that is running on all calls. I refer to obtaining a reference to each of the objects to be modified by the method `findViewById()`. Search for a particular control ID of the object tree within a layout can also be a costly depending on the complexity of the layout itself.

With `ViewHolder` pattern we can save the reference to the controls so we don´t have to search them again.The only `ViewHolder` class will contain a reference to each of the controls that we have to handle our layout, in your case:

```
static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageview;
    Checkbox checkbox;
}
```

We will save the holder with the references in the tag property, presented in every control in Android, with `setTag()`, and we can obtain it with `getTag()`.

Answer (score 0):

These links may help you.
http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/06/16/viewholder-pattern-caching-view-efficiently/
http://vsvydenko.blogspot.in/2011/06/android-use-viewholder.html
Your code might call findViewById() frequently during the scrolling of ListView, which can slow down performance. Even when the Adapter returns an inflated view for recycling, you still need to look up the elements and update them. A way around repeated use of findViewById() is to use the "view holder" design pattern.

A ViewHolder object stores each of the component views inside the tag field of the Layout, so you can immediately access them without the need to look them up repeatedly